# Overo Yocto Qt5 deployment

Tags: qt5, yocto, bootloader, gumstix

I try, for a while now, to install on my `Gumstix Overo a Yocto distribution with Qt5 (5.10.1)`. The goal is to programming a Qt5 application on my Ubuntu virtual machine then cross compile it with QtCreator, [like this](https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-yocto-development), for my Gumstix Overo and run the application on it.

Actually `I'm blocked with the bootable sd card` because when I try to boot the system on the Overo there is an error...

I use the Overo ironSTORM-Y COM and the Tobi platform.

To do all the things I work on an Ubuntu 18.04 distribution with virtual box 5.1.34.
I principaly follow the support of Gumstix [there](https://www.gumstix.com/support/getting-started/create-bootable-microsd-card/) but with some differences.
To prepare the sd card I follow the Gumstix support.
I get the script to format the sd card [there](https://github.com/gumstix/meta-gumstix-extras/blob/dizzy/scripts/mk2partsd). I copy it into a text file from my virtual machine and not from the host machine because of the text formatting like the "line feed (\n)" and the "carriage return (\r)".
At the beginning of the script there is a "space" between the "!" And the "/" there: 
 `#! /bin/sh`. I change it to this `#!/bin/sh`.
I run the script like this: `~$ sudo ./mk2partsd /dev/sdb` at the end I have that: 
`Allocating group tables: done`
`Writing inode tables: done`
`Creating journal (16284 blocks): done`
`Writing superblock and filesystem accounting information: done`
I Download the 3 files that are necessary to boot the Yocto kernel [there](https://catalina.gumstix.com/binaries/6532/).
As it described in the Gumstix support, I download the `MLO`, the `u-boot.img`, and the root file system ".tar.bz2" that is `gumstix-qt5-dev-image-overo.tar.bz2`.
In my home folder I create a yocto folder to save this 3 files `~$ sudo mkdir YoctoMaster`. 
Now I mount the "boot" and the "rootfs" to copy this 3 files into the sd card. So at first I have to create the folder and then mount it.
- `~$ sudo mkdir /media/boot`
- `~$ sudo mkdir /media/rootfs`
- `~$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/boot`
- `~$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb2 /media/rootfs` --> I use ext4, if not, that will not working... 
Finally I can copy the 3 files from the yocto folder.
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sudo cp MLO /media/boot/MLO`
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sudo cp u-boot.img /media/boot/u-boot.img`
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sudo tar -xjvf gumstix-qt5-dev-image-overo.tar.bz2 -C /media/rootfs`
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sync`
Then I umount the disk.
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sudo umount /media/boot`
- `~/YoctoMaster$ sudo umount /media/rootfs`
At this stage I normally have a bootable sd card, so let's try it.
I run the serial reader with `~$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`.
I press "enter" to avoid that the system on the Overo start the boot and the "overo shell" appears as `Overo #`.
Now I have to force the system to start the bootloader that is on the sd card and not on his internal memory. So I do this: 
- `Overo # nand erase 240000 20000`
- `Overo # reset`
This time the system will start with the bootloader and the kernel image that is on the sd card.
**It's at this time that I have the error**
When the kernel is started I have this error: 
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x280000, size 0x800000
 8388608 bytes read: OK
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image! 
Booting from nand with DTS... 
UBI: attaching mtd1 to ubi0
I really need help if someone know how to fix it... 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Removed tags from title; spelling; grammar; noise reduction; layout.

Comment: In bootloader, I think you need to tell U-boot to boot on sdcard. You should try to stop U-boot before starting kernel and see boot commands. `bootm` seems to search only on nand memory. There is maybe also dip switches on board for that.

Comment: @Nayfe: Hello and thanks for your answer. I think it's what I have done no ? I put the `u-boot.img` on the `boot` sd card partition and when I do the `Nand erase....` with " the `reset` I start the kernel.... I don't know how to use the `bootm` command, have you an example or something like this ?

Comment: In u-boot, can you type `env print` or `printenv` and pastebin the result?

Comment: @Nayfe: I retry one more time to install my bootable SD Card but this time I also download the 3 files (MLO, u-boot.img and tar.bz2) from the virtual machin ubuntu 16.04.4. When I boot the kernel [that](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixoveror/src/master/StartKernel) is what I have and the kernel doesn't start it's just blocked. And [that](https://bitbucket.org/falcon1990/gumstixoveror/src/master/UBootprintenv) is the `printenv`.

Comment: don't have access to your bitbucket project

Comment: @Nayfe: Sorry, and now ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution and I poste it for other people.
I do the same thing that I done before but I change two things.
I do all the configuration on my virtual machin Ubunt 16.04.4 included the download and I use [those](https://catalina.gumstix.com/binaries/9955/) files (MLO, u-boot.img and .tar.bz2).
I hope that will help someone.